# Uploading Image File with PHP - File is Empty

Tags: php, forms, image, file, upload

I'm working on uploading an image file from a form to a folder on the server and recording the location in a mysql db via PHP and I'm having a lot of trouble with it. Currently this is my html code for the form:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" class="m-auto" style="max-width:600px">
        <h3 class="my-4"><?php echo "{$family_info['Family_Name']} Family Image Upload";?></h3>
        <hr class="my-4" />
        <div class="form-group mb-3 row"><label for="family_mem5" class="col-md-5 col-form-label">Family Member</label>
            <div class="col-md-7"><select class="form-select custom-select custom-select-lg" name= "family_mem" id="family_mem5">
                    <option></option>
                    <?php
                    while($row = $family_members-> fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) 
                        {        
                        echo "<option value='".$row['Family_Member']."'>".$row['Family_Member']."</option>"; 
                        }
                    ?>
                </select><small class="form-text text-muted">Please select a family member to upload a photo for.</small></div>
        </div>
        <hr class="bg-transparent border-0 py-1" />
        <div class="form-group mb-3 row">
            <label for="image1" class="col-md-5 col-form-label">Image</label>
            <div class="col-md-7"><input type="file" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="image1" name="image" required><small class="form-text text-muted">Please select an image.</small></div>
        </div>
        <hr class="my-4" />
        <div class="form-group mb-3 row"><label for="upload-image8" class="col-md-5 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-7"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Upload Image</button></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my PHP code for the upload.php file that the form POSTs to.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$membernumber = $_SESSION['membernumber'];

$family_member = $_POST['family_mem'];

echo "Member Number: ".$membernumber;
echo "<br />";
echo "Family Member: ".$family_member;
echo "<br />";

/* 
* Custom function to compress image size and 
* upload to the server using PHP 
*/ 
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) { 
// Get image info 
$imgInfo = getimagesize($source); 
$mime = $imgInfo['mime']; 
 
// Create a new image from file 
switch($mime){ 
    case 'image/jpeg': 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); 
        break; 
    case 'image/png': 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source); 
        break; 
    case 'image/gif': 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source); 
        break; 
    default: 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); 
} 
 
// Save image 
imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality); 
 
// Return compressed image 
return $destination; 
} 


// File upload path 
$uploadPath = "uploads/"; 

if ($_FILES['cover_image']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['cover_image']['error'] == 0)
{
echo "empty";
}

// If file upload form is submitted 
$status = $statusMsg = 'Image uploaded for so and so'; 
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{ 
$status = 'error'; 
if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) 
{ 
    // File info    
    $file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
    $fileName = "$family_member.$ext";
    echo 'Filename: '.$fileName;
    $imageUploadPath = $uploadPath . $fileName;
    $fileType = pathinfo($imageUploadPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

    // Allow certain file formats 
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','JPG','png','jpeg','gif'); 
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes))
    { 
        // Image temp source 
        $imageTemp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]; 
        $imageSize = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
         
        // Compress size and upload image 
        $compressedImage = compressImage($imageTemp, $imageUploadPath, 75);
        
        if($compressedImage)
            { 
            $compressedImageSize = filesize($compressedImage);

            $status = 'success'; 
            // $statusMsg = "Image compressed successfully."; 
            }
        else
        { 
            $statusMsg = "Image compress failed!"; 
        } 
    }
    else
    { 
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, & GIF files are allowed to upload.'; 
    } 
}
else
{ 
    $statusMsg = 'Please select an image file to upload.'; 
} 
} 

// Display status message 
echo $statusMsg; 

?>
```

The issue is that the image file is showing up empty as you can see from the check empty code, as if it never makes it over. What could I be doing wrong? I've gotten the upload working in smaller example code before but as soon as I start adding features it falls apart. Right now I'm lost as to why it does not pass the file from the form.

Thank you very much for any help. I'm surprised by how hard moving files is in PHP, or maybe how clueless I am lol.

Comment: unless you use Javascript ( which I don't see ) you'll need to change the form's default `enctype` attribute to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: holy cow, thank you very much! what a duh kind of moment but thank you very much for catching it!